# Retreive post thumbnail and display it as tooltip on hover?

Tags: post-thumbnails, plugin-nextgen-gallery, tooltip

I used a plug in to retrieve all the post from a category. The post is displayed in an unordered list `<ul><li>` and everything if fine, even the `<a>` tags to the post.

Now, for more usefulness (it's a word?), I would like, on hover of the link, to display the first image of the nextgen gallery found in this post. I do not have enough know-how to retro engineer the ngg plugin, but there should be a way to get, let's say the thumbnail of a post and set it as a tooltip.

Comment: what plugin are you using to retrieve all the post from a category?

Comment: If you were to revisit this, does [this](http://www.designhaven.co.uk/2013/10/image-preview-full-size-image-tooltip-nextgen-gallery-wordpress/) help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forget the idea. Doing it with NGG is way too complicated. I am looking for a different solution. Magic gallery (PRO) look good to me